# FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!uid changes when creating a new user (which is not logged in)

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have just noticed that when I am logged in as a `User A` and and I create a new `User B` inside the app using:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: userEmail, password: pass);
```

then... uid of `User A` (fetched with `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!uid`) changes to the uid of newly created `UserB` although `User B` **is not logged in.**
I just created account for `User B` and never logged in as `User B`.

In this case, because I am using `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!uid` in several places of my app, it starts to "think" I am already `User B` while I am still logged in as `User A`.

I thought `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!uid` gives you the uid of the user who is logged in but it looks otherwise..
Can anyone help me how I can get the uid of the user who is really logged in?

Many thanks upfront for any support!

Comment: This is expected behavior. Creating a username also causes a login, so user B is really the logged-in user.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, Creating new user will change **authState** because the new user will be logged in. To avoid this you have to create new of **FirebaseAuth.instance**. Use the following snippet for the same.

```
// Create New firebase app instance.
FirebaseApp tempApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(name: 'Some_Random_String_for_app_name', options: Firebase.app().options);
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: tempApp).createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass);
Map<String, dynamic> _user = {
                'sUID': userCredential.user!.uid,
                'sName': name,
                'sEmail': email,
              };
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help and above snippet. It almost works, I am getting the error that I cannot use tempApp in userCredential:
`The argument type 'Future<FirebaseApp>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FirebaseApp'`
Do you know how to walk around it?

Comment: user _async_ and _await_,
you might be getting error at  this line ->
`FirebaseApp tempApp = *await* Firebase.initializeApp(name: 'Some_Random_String_for_app_name', options: Firebase.app().options);`
- make sure you are using newer version of firebase package

Comment: UPDATE : You can refer to this gist [https://gist.github.com/Dhirajraje/9e9b0afa959202fe31ea85541038ffc9](https://gist.github.com/Dhirajraje/9e9b0afa959202fe31ea85541038ffc9)

Comment: Wonderful, it works! Many thanks @Dhirajraje